# error when installing ROS on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to install ROS using this tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

when trying this command
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

found error :

sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [116, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted

what the wrong ?? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44711/error-when-installing-ros-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is your user account member of the group "admin"? By default ubuntu grants permission to execute sudo to users of that group.

Otherwise, [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2048031) might help you. Apparently, updating ubuntu and restarting the computer solved a similar issue for another ubuntu user.

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1